# Codeigniter routing on a ubuntu live server running on a virtual machine

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine

I am really frustrated.
Everything was working fine on a windows 7 localhost before but after I moved the codeigniter project to a ubuntu server running on a virtual box, everything becomes so frustrating.

The ubuntu server running on a virtual box has an ip address let's say 127.0.0.1 and the host ip address is 127.0.0.2.
In the virtual box, I mapped the host ip and guest ip using the NAT adapter.
So I can access the guest ip from host browser.

In the config.php, the `base_url` is like this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` so the `base_url` is `http://127.0.0.1`

and the default controller is `$route['default_controller'] = 'login';`

On the host browser, the default page from the default controller can be loaded perfectly, but it does not apply the rest of the pages accessed using base_url, the pages cannot be found on the server when they are actually there.

```
<form name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('login/login'); ?>">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="txtEmail" value="<?php set_value('txtEmail') ?>" name="txtEmail">  
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="txtPassword" value="<?php set_value('txtPassword') ?>" name="txtPassword">  
  <a href="#" class="forgot">forgot password?</a>
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin">
</form>
```

In the form above, the controller `login/login` cannot be found.

How can I set the routes.php in order for all the pages can be accessed using the base_url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem, this issue occurred because in unix the file name is case sensitive and in windows it's not. I had to rename the controllerss and models' name starting with an uppercase letter in unix system

Answer (score 0):

in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: still same thing happens. this page was not found on this server

Comment: can you give me live server domain??

Comment: I think I know the problem. I should set the base_url to empty and index_page to index.php and use site_url instead of base_url

Comment: It's not because of the config but it's because in unix the file name is case sensitive and in windows it's not. I have to rename the controllers and models' name starting with an uppercase letter in unix system